# How to convert string to json in Angular?

Tags: node.js, json, angular

Starting to the following kind of string:

```
const json = '{"list":"[{"additionalInformation": {"source": "5f645d7d94-c6ktd"}, "alarmName": "data", "description": "Validation Error. Fetching info has been skipped.", "eventTime": "2020-01-27T14:42:44.143200 UTC", "expires": 2784, "faultyResource": "Data", "name": "prisco", "severity": "Major"}]"}'
```

How can I manage this as a JSON?  The following approach doesn't work

```
const obj = JSON.parse(json );
unuspected result
```

How can I parse it correctly?

In conclusion, I should extract the part relative to the first item list and then parse the JSON that it contains.

Comment: could you add information on what you are expecting because your code seams fine.

Comment: I would like to extract the json, should I remove []?

Comment: Well it depends, You json is an array, if you don't want to keep the array, you could retrieve the first element. `JSON.parse('[{"result":true, "count":42}]')[0]`.

Comment: It is already a valid JSON string. "doesn't work" how?

Comment: json string updated

Comment: The updated json is not valid; the `list` value should not be quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. The following is the valid version of your JSON:

```
const json= {
    "list": [ {
        "additionalInformation": {
            "source": "5f645d7d94-c6ktd"
        },
        "alarmName": "data",
        "description": "Validation Error. Fetching info has been skipped.",
        "eventTime": "2020-01-27T14:42:44.143200 UTC",
        "expires": 2784,
        "faultyResource": "Data",
        "name": "prisco",
        "severity": "Major"
      }
    ]
}
```

The above is already a JSON and parsing it as JSON again throws an error.

`JSON.parse()` parse string/ text and turn it into JavaScript object. The string/ text should be in a JSON format or it will throw an error.

**Update:**
Create a function to clean your string and prepare it for `JSON.parse()`:

```
cleanString(str) {
    str = str.replace('"[', '[');
    str = str.replace(']"', ']');
  return str;
}
```

And use it like:

```
json = this.cleanString(json);
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

**Demo:**

```js
let json = '{"list":"[{"additionalInformation": {"source": "5f645d7d94-c6ktd"}, "alarmName": "data", "description": "Validation Error. Fetching info has been skipped.", "eventTime": "2020-01-27T14:42:44.143200 UTC", "expires": 2784, "faultyResource": "Data", "name": "prisco", "severity": "Major"}]"}';
json = cleanString(json);
console.log(JSON.parse(json));

function cleanString(str) {
 str = str.replace('"[', '[');
 str = str.replace(']"', ']');
  return str;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to take the object by doing something like : json['list']

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes from around the array brackets to make the json valid:

```
const json = '{"list":[{"additionalInformation": {"source": "5f645d7d94-c6ktd"}, "alarmName": "data", "description": "Validation Error. Fetching info has been skipped.", "eventTime": "2020-01-27T14:42:44.143200 UTC", "expires": 2784, "faultyResource": "Data", "name": "prisco", "severity": "Major"}]}'
```

Comment: Demo in answer from Maihan